# Convert Images to webp with Node

Tags: node.js, webp, imagemin, imagemin-webp

I have a script to convert images to node, but am having an issue where I receive the successful message, yet nothing is output.

```
import imagemin from "imagemin";
import webp from "imagemin-webp";

var outputFolder = "./FSS-assets/webp";            // Output folder
var PNGImages = "./FSS-assets/*.png";         // PNG images
var JPEGImages = "./FSS-assets/*.jpg";        // JPEG images

imagemin([PNGImages], outputFolder, {
  plugins: [webp({
      lossless: true // Losslessly encode images
  })]
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Images converted!");
});

imagemin([JPEGImages], outputFolder, {
  plugins: [webp({
    quality: 65 // Quality setting from 0 to 100
  })]
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Images converted!");
});
```

I am running

- node v14.16.0
- imagemin v8
- imagemin-webp v6

I have also tried using a relative folder path to no avail. This is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `imagemin` has 2 params `input` and `options` You are giving 3params.

From the [Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin):

```
imagemin(input, options?)

Returns Promise<object[]> in the format {data: Buffer, sourcePath: string, destinationPath: string}.
```

So for your code it will be:

```
imagemin([PNGImages], {
  destination: outputFolder,
  plugins: [webp({
      lossless: true // Losslessly encode images
  })]
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Images converted!");
});
```

Comment: That was absolutely it! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to adjust your parameter structure slightly. To be ([images], { destination: ‘/output directory’, plugins: {});

```
const files = await imagemin(['images/*.{jpg,png}'], {
destination: 'build/images',
plugins: [
    imageminJpegtran(),
    imageminPngquant({
        quality: [0.6, 0.8]
    })
]
});
```

Hope this helps & works.